# How to make one imageview disappear when another imageview is pressed?

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I'm trying to make a gun simulator app where a row of bullets disappear one by one with every click of the gun. What Java code is needed in order to make bullet1 disappear when you click the gun the first time and to make bullet2 disappear the second time the gun is pressed?

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gun"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/gunimage"
    android:onClick="shoot"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bullet"
    android:id="@+id/bullet1"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bullet"
    android:id="@+id/bullet2"/>
```

Comment: use setvisibitlity inside the onclick listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
firstbullet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    secondbullet..setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

    secondbullet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    firstbullet..setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```